# Node.js to get/determine OS version

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to determine whether some script that is being executed is running a particular version of Mac OSX.  I realize I can exec/spawn the command:

```
sw_vers -productVersion
```

Is there a way to do this synchronously (similar to process.arch) without [node-exec-sync](https://github.com/jeremyfa/node-exec-sync)?  I realize its an accepted bad practice to spawn/exec synchronously, but I don't see another way.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

you could use  [the OS module](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform) like this:

```
var os = require('os');
os.platform(); // 'darwin'
os.release(); //'10.8.0'
```

and then map the release version to a specific version of Mac OS X.

Darwin to Mac OS X mappings can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29#Release_history)

Comment: os.release is supposedly the same as `uname -a` which gives the kernel version.  On OSX 10.8.2 for example, it returns 12.2.0.  I suppose I can find kernel mappings to OSX versions, but I figure that is less reliable.

Comment: Well, once you get the `os.platform()` value, you can then run code which picks up the actual OS version from some other platform specific command.

Comment: added link to release history.

Comment: According to the article, the mapping is more reliable than I thought.  The major version # stays unique while the minor version actually corresponds to the minor version in the OSX version.  Thanks!

Comment: `os.release` on macOS 11 returns 20.3 Obviously does not return the OS version.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above in AndyD's answer's comments, `os.release()` returns the kernel version. If you want to get the same version number that a user sees in the "About this Mac" UI, you can read and parse out `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`, like so:

```
const plist = require('plist');
let versionInfo = plist.parseFileSync('/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist');
console.log(JSON.stringify(versionInfo));
```

https://github.com/kevinsawicki/node-plist