# restrict electron app to able to install only on windows 7 and above?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have created and built the electron app using eletron-builder, everything is working fine but I wanted to restrict the app installation to only windows 7 and above.

for example if the user wants to install the app on windows xp or windows 2003 it should error saying installation requires windows 7 or above.

I'm very new to the electron and searched the internet for the solution. I didn't find any solution yet.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916050/2550156

Comment: thank you @pergy but it only says how to get the os version in node. I'm looking for a solution where the install app wizard itself should complain about not supported operating system i.e what parameter to be set in electron-builder configuration? or something like that